# Magento2 include new css file

Tags: magento2, css, frontend, less

I want to include a new css file `styles.css`. Steps I've taken:

1) switch to developer mode (`magento deploy:mode:set developer`);

2) edit `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` and include my theme with my new file `styles`:

```
my_theme: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'My_company/my_theme',
        locale: 'en_GB',
        files: [
            'css/styles',
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

3) In `My_company/my_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`
I add it like this  `<css src="css/styles.css" />`

4) In `My_company/my_theme/web/css/syles.less` I add `@import 'source/_theme.less';` and then have `My_company/my_theme/web/css/_theme.less` with different variables.

5) Run `grunt clean`, `grunt exec`, `grunt less` and it went along fine without errors:

```
Running "less:my_theme" (less) task
File pub/static/frontend/My_company/my_theme/en_GB/css/styles.css created: 435 B → 992 B
```

Tried removing everything from the var folder and from `pub/static` except the `.htaccess`. Cleared cache, regenerating static folder `magento setup:static-content:deploy`. Checked in the admin that my theme is selected in `web > design`. Reindexed.

In view page source magento is still looking for `pub/static/frontend/My_company/my_theme/en_GB/css/styles-m.css` (which returns a 404) and not including `pub/static/frontend/My_company/my_theme/en_GB/css/styles.css`

Where can I look next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the logs. In system.log I found this error:

```
Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1: Please correct the XML data and try again

Theme layout update file '/var/www/app/design/frontend/My_company/my_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml' is not valid.
```

It would have been great if developer mode broke the page highlighting the xml error.